# JSON data for d3 line and bar graphs

Tags: json, d3.js, graphing

I am new to the d3 graphing library and all the tutorials I've seen for loading JSON data for a graph have been using a url and a callback function. I already have the JSON data in a JSON object in the same function in which I am looking to graph (the JSON data is stored in a variable in the same file as the graphing function). How do I use that JSON object in my graphs? This is my code. The JSON object is called 'data'.

```
            function showBargraph() {
            var calories = 0;
            var protein = 0;
            var carbohydrates = 0;
            var fat = 0;
            for (var i in graphdata) {
                calories = calories + parseInt(graphdata[i].calories);
                protein = protein + parseInt(graphdata[i].protein);
                carbohydrates = carbohydrates + parseInt(graphdata[i].carbohydrates);
                fat = fat + parseInt(graphdata[i].fat);
            }
            //THIS IS THE JSON OBJECT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            var data = {
                'calories': calories,
                'protein': protein,
                'carbohydrates': carbohydrates,
                'fat': fat
            }
            // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
            var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
            width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // append the svg object to the body of the page
            var svg = d3.select("#myBarChart")
                .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                    .attr("transform",
                        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            d3.json(data, function(d) {
                console.log(d);
            });
            // X axis
            var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([ 0, width ])
            .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Country; }))
            .padding(0.2);
            svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
            .selectAll("text")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
                .style("text-anchor", "end");

            // Add Y axis
            var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 13000])
            .range([ height, 0]);
            svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
            var trace1 = {
                        x: ['Calories', 'Protein', 'Carbohydrates', 'Fat'],
                        y: [calories, protein, carbohydrates, fat],
                        type: 'bar'
                    };
```

Comment: Hi Rohith, I do not understand why you are trying to use the d3.json function at all. Just usu your object directly. d3.json function is used only to load the data from an external source.

Comment: Yes, I ended up figuring out that I could use the object directly. I was under the assumption for some reason that I could not use the plotly graphing library when deploying a website and was trying to change my graphs to the d3 library but plotly.js is open-source and free to use so I didn't end up needing to use d3. The D3 library seems to be a little syntactically complex and hard to understand. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not a problem. If you are new to the d3, you can check my course I released this week on Udemy. If you will use this link you will get it for free. The coupon is valid for one day only. https://www.udemy.com/course/d3js-the-art-of-data-visualization/?couponCode=805CA150FD33DD6EA6EE